Dimensions in EMF metric not showing up in the CloudWatch Console
I have implemented a Metric client that emits CloudWatch metrics by writing to a log using EMF. One such EMF log is as follows:
{
    "_aws": {
        "Timestamp": 1712793019652,
        "CloudWatchMetrics": [
            {
                "Dimensions": [
                    [
                        "Service",
                        "Operation",
                        "Team"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Service",
                        "Operation"
                    ],
                    [
                        "Service"
                    ]
                ],
                "Metrics": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Latency",
                        "Unit": "Time"
                    },
                    {
                        "Name": "Error",
                        "Unit": "Count"
                    }
                ],
                "Namespace": "Application/GraphAPI"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Service": "GraphAPI",
    "Operation": "DeleteChild",
    "Team": <team_id>,
    "Latency": 54.50842199998442,
    "Error": 0
}

I would expect to see the Service,Operation,Team dimension in the CloudWatch; however, it is not there. I DO see dimensions for the other two though.
Is this expected behavior? Why am I not seeing that dimension? Could I be hitting some quota?
